# CSV location code decoder

Tags: qgis-processing

Is the a way reverse a CSV cell code that was generated from PyQGIS? This is for a location point.

The code is

0101000020E6100000C5DC58CD04F65BC0CC755D611AB54040

Comment: Looks like hexadecimal display of Well-Known Binary (WKB).

Comment: Yes WKB can be converted to Well Known Text (WKT) POINT(-111.84404309919326 33.41486756385311) https://rodic.fr/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/geom_converter.html

Comment: Wow! Thank you, Mapperz. Do you know a python code for that?